# TypeScripts "never type not visible for JSDoc?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I'm using JSDoc to add typings to a JavaScript project, but it looks like TypeScripts `never` type is not available for the typings.

This is the error I get:

```
/.../src/components/Content/TwoColumn.js
  11:0  warning  The type 'never' is undefined  jsdoc/no-undefined-types
```

Can I use this type with JSDoc somehow?